# Group by colors

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro :

```
Sub ColorfilesDuplicates()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xChar As String
    Dim xCellPre As Range
    Dim xCIndex As Long
    Dim xCol As Collection
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
      xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
      xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If
    Set xRg = Range("V1:V5600")
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xCIndex = 2
    Set xCol = New Collection
    For Each xCell In xRg
      On Error Resume Next
      xCol.Add xCell, xCell.Text
      If Err.Number = 457 Then
        xCIndex = xCIndex + 1
        Set xCellPre = xCol(xCell.Text)
        If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex
        xCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex
      ElseIf Err.Number = 9 Then
        MsgBox "Too many duplicate companies!", vbCritical, "Kutools for Excel"
        Exit Sub
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

that works fine. Ithe idea is to fill the same value files with the same background color. The problem is that it works till the first 200 cells more or less. I have a sheet with 6000 rows, and is not doing its work completely...what am I doing wrong?. I have no idea what´s going on ....

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I suggest using a `Dictionary` instead of a `Collection`. You can check if a key exists and skip the type of error checking you're currently using.

Comment: And whath would it change? It works fine in that way,,,I don´t know why works till file 200. I don´t know what u mean or what line to change...

Comment: Start by removing the `On Error Resume Next` around line 11.  Doesn't seem to be any point to that one, and it will hide any relevant errors.

Comment: thanks, it´s done. But I still have the problem....why it stops filling the cells ?

Comment: If you have more than 54 duplicates, you are probably running out of colors.  Once xCIndex reaches 56, that's it.  Anything greater than 57 will throw an error and because of use of ElseIf you are never seeing the error.  `ElseIf Err.Number = 9`  should become it's own If/End If block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it like this:

```
Sub ColorDuplicates()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xTxt As String
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xChar As String
Dim xCellPre As Range
Dim xCIndex As Long
Dim xCol As Collection
Dim I As Long
On Error Resume Next
If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
Else
xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
End If
Set xRg = RANGE("V1:V6000")
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
xCIndex = 2
Set xCol = New Collection
For Each xCell In xRg
On Error Resume Next
xCol.Add xCell, xCell.Text
If Err.Number = 457 Then
xCIndex = xCIndex + 1
Set xCellPre = xCol(xCell.Text)
If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCellPre.Interior.Color = 
RGB(xRed, xGreen, xBlue)
xCell.Interior.Color = xCellPre.Interior.Color
ElseIf Err.Number = 9 Then
MsgBox "Too many duplicate companies!", vbCritical, "Kutools for Excel"
Exit Sub
End If
xRed = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
xGreen = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
xBlue = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
On Error GoTo 0
Next
End Sub
```

No dictionary needed